# Selecting records activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I got this date string :

```
Mon, 03 Feb 2014 13:51:34 UTC +00:00
```

How can I select records which have created_at 10 minutes more or less than the date time above?

**Question update:**

I mean the interval all minutes starting from that time above and going back 10 minutes or 10 minutes in advance, so in that time range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date = DateTime.parse('Mon, 03 Feb 2014 13:51:34 UTC +00:00')
```

If `Klass` is the Active Record Model use [range-conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions)

```
Klass.where(created_at: (date - 10.minutes)..(date + 10.minutes))
```